# Python Tkinter Entry how to get width of the entry

Tags: python, validation, tkinter, width, tkinter-entry

```
vcmd = (self.register(self.validate_entry_len), '%P', '%W')

ip_entry = tk.Entry(ip_frame, width=15, validate='key', vcmd=vcmd)
port_entry = tk.Entry(port_frame, width=5, validate='key', vcmd=vcmd)

def validate_entry_len(self, P, W):
    entry = self.master.nametowidget(W)
    if len(P) <= !!!width of entry!!!:
        return True

    self.bell()
    return False
```

So I am trying to validate the text inside the entry whether it exceeds the max length or not. I have two entry widgets with different length. I want to use the same validation function with different lengths for each so that I don't need to make two validation function when the only difference is the max length. Therefore, I am trying to use the width of the widget. However, I can't find a way to get the width.

Comment: By `!!!width of entry!!!` do you mean `len(entry.get())`?

Comment: That's the length of the width content. I want the value I set when I was making the Entry 'width=15'

Comment: Oh, the width of the widget itself? So `entry['width']`?

Comment: OH YES that! Thanks. please post that as answer so I can put that as answer.

Comment: Looks like `entry['width']` would work sometimes, but then give the wrong value if the width changes. Use the method in the linked question/answer instead; it's more robust.

Comment: I tried winfo_width() before but it gave me 90 instead 15. I think it returns width in pixels. I need width as the number of characters which entry['width'] is perfect. My entry doesn't expand/fill either.

Comment: I see - I didn't know that. I'll reopen and add it as an answer, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the character width of the `Entry` widget with `entry['width']`. Keep in mind that this may not be reliably updated if the widget is modified.